# Users enter Forward Slash "/" in asp.net MVC 3 url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

Using .Net 4, isn't it possible to include forward slash in route parameters or one should **force the user to use hyphen** `-` instead

Example: 
`mysite.com/user/{id}/{year}` maps to
`mysite.com/user/01/2012`

*where `{id} = {user/01}` and `{year} = 2012` in the example above*

if this is the last route parameter it would be easier as pointed in the answers below. but it is not

I have read these, same questions as mine

- [URL-encoded slash in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591694/url-encoded-slash-in-url)
- [How to pass special characters so ASP.NET MVC can handle correctly query string data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373599/how-to-pass-special-characters-so-asp-net-mvc-can-handle-correctly-query-string)
- [How to make ASP.NET Routing escape route values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174538/how-to-make-asp-net-routing-escape-route-values)

but I didn't really get what I want. I could use this solutions if I want to generate the URL.

**But what happens if the use type the url in the browser?**

Or one should avoid that and force the user to use other formats like replacing "/" with "-"? as:
mysite.com/user/usr-01/2012

Comment: So what is the actual question here?  Try listing what you want vs what actually happens.

Comment: I have by question in bold already. Should one force user to use hyphen or is still possible to allow them to use "/". Or is it possible to intercept the request before it is resolved into route parameters? Thanks

Comment: I think it's still not exactly clear what you want to achieve? If a user types in an invalid URL, you can respond with a friendly 404 that explains that this is not a valid url, and contains a link to user search form. Or give us an example of the url you would like to use.

Comment: the question is clear enough and there are examples included - I updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loosely interpreted:  *Can a route-parameter include a forward-slash ?*

Answer: **No.** Just avoid that.

Comment: You mean I should tell my users to replace "/" with " - "? It could be part of my documentation if that is the last solution.

Comment: Why/where would your users type a '/' in the first place?

Comment: their user id is like `mhis/2012/001` I don't have control over that except if I tell them swap "/" for " - " every time

Comment: Users shouldn't be typing (complicated) urls. Tools should create those URLs and use a proper encoding (`-` will do).

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right.
The userID is "mhis/001", and the year is 2012, then you would like to use an URL like this:
`http://localhost:59025/User/mhis/001/2012`

#### Global.asax - define the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "UserDetails", // Route Name
                "User/{idpart1}/{idpart2}/{year}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "User", action = "Details", year= UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
            );
```

The "year" parameter is set as optional, so if the user type `http://localhost:59025/User/mhis/001/2012`, year will be 2012, if doesn't type anything, year will be null.

#### A dummy user class:

```
public class User
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// just a helper to get the first part of the userID
    /// </summary>
    public string IDPart1 { get { return Id.Split('/')[0]; } }
    /// <summary>
    /// just a helper to get the second part of the userID
    /// </summary>
    public string IDPart2 { get { return Id.Split('/')[1]; } }
}
```

Added two helper properties to the User class take the user name apart (IDPart1, IDPart2), so it's easier to use in the view

#### The controller with a dummy user list:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// user list...
    /// </summary>
    List<User> _users = new List<User> {
        new User{ Id="mhis/001", Name="John Smith"},
        new User{ Id="mhis/002", Name="Some Body Else"}
    };    

    /// <summary>
    /// This is actually a user list, but...
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_users);
    }

    public ActionResult Details(string idpart1, string idpart2, int? year)
    {
        //do what you have to do with the year...
        ViewBag.year = year;            

        string realUserID = String.Format(@"{0}/{1}", idpart1, idpart2);
        var user = _users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == realUserID);

        return View(user);
    }
}
```

#### The list view:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>            
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { idpart1 = item.IDPart1, idpart2 = item.IDPart2 }) 
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

The interesting part is this: `@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { idpart1 = item.IDPart1, idpart2 = item.IDPart2 })`, sou you get what you want.

#### Details view:

```
    @model MvcApplication1.Controllers.User

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    }
    @if(Model != null) {
    <h2>Details</h2>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>

        The year is: "@ViewBag.year"

        <div class="display-label">Name</div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <p>@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</p>

    } else {//this should be handled in the controller...
        <h2>User not found!</h2> 
    }
```